# Android parsing org.json.JSONObject object has no "getFloat" method. What do I do?

Tags: android, json

In my app I'm creating a JSON object.
Somewhere along the way I insert floats (location longitude and latitude) in it.

Then send it to server.

When I get it from the server and try parsing it, I realized there is no getFloat method?

Will getInt do the job or should I save it as a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JSONObject object has no “getFloat” method. What do I do?

with JSON you use `getDouble()` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getDouble(java.lang.String)))

Comment: Anyone know the reason JSON decided not to make getFloat? It's resulting in doubling memory use in many areas where it isn't necessary.